# Is there an AWS solution of an alarm system for failed python scripts?

Tags: php, python, amazon-web-services, logging, alarm

I need an system that could check if many python scripts have run comletely.

The scripts would scrape data and output it to a corresponding xml file.

If the script fails there might be no xml file or error messages in the logs files. PHP files run the python scripts.

Is there a simple solution using an AWS service that would trigger alarms when a python script is not functioning fully?

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule cron job to attain that.

Comment: fastest gun in the west or comment only answer ?

Comment: How could I check with python if there is an xml file called xxx in a certain folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python

Answer (score 0):

If you modify (or wrap) your scripts to send a metric to CloudWatch on success, you can then configure an alert for [insufficient data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html).

Comment: Is there a similar open source alternative to CloudWatch?

Comment: You asked for an AWS solution.